# What would be a recent follow-up or alternative to Pylyshyn's 1984 book on "Computation and Cognition: Toward a Foundation for Cognitive Science"?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, reference-request, philosophy-of-mind, cognitive-sciences

I was exposed to Zenon Pylyshyn's work through my master's thesis work in Cognitive Science. Recently, I picked up his 1984 book on "Computation and Cognition: Toward a Foundation for Cognitive Science"[0]. I'm aware that in the decades since, cognitive science has become more pluralistic in the sense different people have different views on what should be the goals and foundations of their research, and some people even preferring the "shup-up and calculate" attitude. Even then, I found the first chapter of Pylyshyn's book to be relevant today. However, I have felt the book to be heavy, and some people have suggested that it could have been better written. I was wondering if I should continue with the rest of the book, or if there are some more recent recommendations.

What I seem to be looking for is another "Foundations for Cognitive Science" but something that merges (and not merely lists) the pluralistic turn the field has taken in recent decades. From brief paper readings during the philosophy courses during my master's, it didn't seem as if all the different approaches are incompatible with each other. Compatibility seems to exist within the nuances and I wonder if anyone has put them together into a book.

1. I picked up Bermudez's "Cognitive Science: An Introduction to the Science of the Mind" - I felt it okay for an introductory textbook, but it refuses to go into depth and nuances of any of the concepts or experiments.
2. Another book I touched is "Cognitive Science: An Introduction to Mind and Brain" by
   Daniel Kolak, William Hirstein, Peter Mandik, Jonathan Waskan. I went through its first chapter and it seemed better than [1], but it still didn't feel as weaving-together as [0].
3. Yet another recommendation I had come across was Cambridge's Handbook of Cognitive Science. As it is intended to be, from the first chapter I read and the second I glanced through, it seemed more akin to an encyclopaedic entry rather than something more cohesive.

Thus, [2] seems like the best successor to Pylyshyn's 1984 work, and I was wondering if anyone would recommend something more suitable.